# Remix error : Function declared as view but this potentially modifies state

Tags: solidity, remix, events, view

This code is inside a view function and gives the error : Function declared as view but this potentially modifies state.

```
if ( auction.iS == false){      //check if such auction exists
emit NoSuchAuction(msg.sender, _auctionName); 
return; }
```

NoSuchAuction() is an event.
_auctionName is a string.
auction is a structure and iS is a boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Events take a place in the blockchain which can be filtered. But functionality of a view function cannot make any changes in the blockchain state. That's why you are getting the error. Use `return`, to get the parameters back, if event is required, remove the `view` from it. `View` & `event` cannot live together.

Know more about state change : http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=emit#view-functions

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of the event and put the bool in the return list.